# How to get the date of a day passed as Week Day Number? | mySQL

Tags: mysql

Wondering how this can be done..How to get the date of a day passed as Week Day Number from this week. For example if I pass `3` it will return Wed `4/20`. If I submit `1` it will return Monday `4/18`.

Essentially I need to do the opposite of `SELECT WEEKDAY('2022-04-21');`

By passing `(3)` to get the date `2022-04-21` as a response.

Can this accomplished in mySQL?

Comment: How will your code know what week it is?   It looks like (3) is not needed to get today's date.

Comment: Should this always be related to the current week, or is it specific to the week you have in your examples? i.e. If you ran this next week, would the results change?

Comment: It needs to be based of off the current week always

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably want something like

```
SELECT DATE_ADD((CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE())) DAY), INTERVAL 3 DAY);
```

where you can replace the 3 near the end with your input.

`CURDATE()` gets you the current date, so `(CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE())) DAY)` gets you the start of the current week. The `DATE_ADD` function is then used to add your input parameter to the start of the current week.

This should be the opposite of the `WEEKDAY` function like you wanted.

Edited to add: I realize I mixed my syntaxes (using a `- interval` for subtracting the days and then using `date_add` for adding it back on). It would probably be cleaner to use one or the other. So:

```
SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE())) DAY + INTERVAL 3 DAY;
```

**Edited based on comments:** The answers above use your example of passing 3 to get Thursday (2022-04-21). If you want 0 to be a Sunday (and therefore 3 to be a Wednesday 2022-04-20), you can subtract one more.

So something like:

```
SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE())+1) DAY + INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

or

```
SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE())) DAY - Interval 1 DAY + INTERVAL 3 DAY
```

or even

```
SELECT CURDATE() - INTERVAL (WEEKDAY(CURDATE())) DAY + INTERVAL 3-1 DAY
```

where the 3 is your parameter and the -1 is constant.

Comment: This is essentially what I need but I am looking for 0 to represent Sunday not Monday

Comment: @StephanieSmith I have added some versions with that. Note that your original question does say that 3 should return 2022-04-21 near the end (although I now see that at the beginning you said 3 should return 2022-04-20 as well).